# Prism Templates pack vs2010 install location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, prism

Does anybody know once you install the prism templates vs2010 where are they Installed?
I cannot find in anywhere.
I am using windows 7

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself.Just used the registryeditor and found where they get installed.

Answer (score 0):

May I know why u want to know where it installed? You could manage installed templates/extensions on Extension Manager in VS2010 (Tools > Extension Manager...)

Comment: hi
Simple I want to look at the code.Does managing templates also tells you where they are installed?

Do you know where they get installed?